# CSS class nesting not working

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS class and I want to make sure that whenever a `h2` tag is assigned that class, additional CSS is given to the `h2` tag on top of the original class. Here is what I currently have for CSS and HTML but it is currently not rendering out the text-align class.

```css
.aligncenter {
 clear: both;
 color: #000000
 h2{
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div>
<h2 class="aligncenter"> H2 Text that should be black and centered</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with regular css. The only way to achieve what you want with regular css is like this:

```
.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    color: #000000
}

h2.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    color: #000000
    text-align: center;
}
```

To do nesting and other cool stuff you need some css extension language like SASS

Comment: I am using SCSS and have been seeing something like this a bit in the code base but haven't been able to make it work myself

Comment: Are you converting your scss files to css?

Comment: Yeah I am -  using a sass compiler. I suppose thats where it begins to break down

Answer (score 0):

```css
.aligncenter {
 clear: both;
 color: #000000
 h2{
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div>
<h2 class="aligncenter"> H2 Text that should be black and centered</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
h2.aligncenter {
        clear: both;
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
        }
</style>

    <div><h2 class="aligncenter"> H2 Text that should be black and centered</h2></div>
 <!-- end snippet -->
```